# How to use "joinEager" along with raw sql query in Objection/Knex?

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js, postgresql-9.5, objection.js

I have managed to write a raw query that allows me to get all products inside a category, even the products inside the category's sub categories all the way down the tree.

I am using a raw query because I didn't know how to use objection's / knex api to do so.

The problem I am having is that I also want to join the related tables, in this case, for my products I have "products_meta" and "categories"

Even though I know I can simply modify the raw query to do that, I would like to know if there is a simpler way by using some objection/knex methods, like joinEager.

My code so far looks something like this: (the sql string below is just getting all products inside a category and its subcategories, this is not the problem)

```
 const sql = `
                with recursive get_subcols as(
                    select id
                    from collections
                    where "parentId" = ${req.params.id}
                    union all
                    select c.id
                    from collections as c
                    inner join get_subcols gs
                    on c."parentId" = gs.id
                ), get_all_collections as (
                    select id from collections
                    where id = ${req.params.id}
                    union
                    select * from get_subcols
                ), get_all_products as (
                    select p.*, c.name as collection
                    from products as p
                    join "collectionProducts" cp
                    on cp."productId" = p.id
                    join get_all_collections gac
                    on cp."collectionId" = gac.id
                    left join collections as c
                    on cp."collectionId" = c.id
                )

                select * from get_all_products;
            `

            const result = await Collection.knex().raw(sql)
            const products =  result.rows
```

My question is, is it possible to do something like this:

```
.joinEager('[meta, collections]')
```

to the results so I can also join the related tables in the result?

Comment: You need to write suitable relation mappings to your `Product` model and then you will be able to use `.eager` and `.joinEager`.  Docs are here http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#relationmappings

Comment: @MikaelLepistö Yes, but how can I chain .joinEager()  .. When I do:  await Product.knex().raw(sql).joinEager() it throws error saying: TypeError: Product.knex(...).raw(...).joinEager is not a function  .. How can I use joinEager together with a raw query?

Comment: You don't want to do that. Normally you should never even need `Model.knex().raw()` with objection. That will just create plain `knex` query and won't do anything `objection` specific stuff. With `objection` you should do queries through `Model.query()...`

Comment: Maybe watching this will be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyQ1MTVjYK8